# WebSocket connection establishment error from browser

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have mosquitto MQTT broker running on my machine. And I want to run the MQTT client from browser. This is what I have done in a Django app:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mosquitto Websockets</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="{% static 'js/mqttws31-min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/config.js' %}" type="text/javasacript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mqtt;
    var reconnectTimeout = 2000;

    function MQTTconnect() {
        host = '127.0.0.1';
        port = 1883;
        useTLS = false;
        cleansession = true;
        username = null;
        password = null;
        mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, port,
                    "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

        /*mqtt = new Messaging.Client(
                        host,
                        port,
                        "web_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100,
                        10));
        */
        var options = {
            timeout: 3,
            useSSL: useTLS,
            cleanSession: cleansession,
            onSuccess: onConnect,
            onFailure: function (message) {
                $('#status').val("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage + "Retrying");
                setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
            }
        };

        mqtt.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
        mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

        if (username != null) {
            options.userName = username;
            options.password = password;
        }
        console.log("Host="+ host + ", port=" + port + " TLS = " + useTLS + " username=" + username + " password=" + password);
        mqtt.connect(options);
    }

    function onConnect() {
        $('#status').val('Connected to ' + host + ':' + port);
        // Connection succeeded; subscribe to our topic
        mqtt.subscribe(topic, {qos: 0});
        $('#topic').val(topic);
    }

    function onConnectionLost(response) {
        setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
        $('#status').val("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage + ". Reconnecting");

    };

    function onMessageArrived(message) {

        var topic = message.destinationName;
        var payload = message.payloadString;

        $('#ws').prepend('<li>' + topic + ' = ' + payload + '</li>');
    };


    $(document).ready(function() {
        MQTTconnect();
    });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Mosquitto Websockets</h1>
    <div>
        <div>Subscribed to <input type='text' id='topic' disabled />
        Status: <input type='text' id='status' size="80" disabled /></div>

        <ul id='ws' style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET   mqttws31-min.js:15
Host=127.0.0.1, port=1883 TLS = false username=null password=null   (index):47
```

I am new to this so am unable to resolve this. Any help?

Edit1:
I tweaked the config file and now it successfully connects to test.mosquitto.org:8080. I subscribed to #, but it is unable to retrieve the published message. I think function `onMessageArrived(message)` is not working. There are no errors in the console so unable to identify any errors.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you have configured the broker to accept websockets connections on port 1883? By default you would expect this to be listening for MQTT connections, not websockets.

Try putting the following in your config file:

```
listener 8080
protocol websockets
```

As Scott says, you could try connecting your client to test.mosquitto.org:8080 to see if it works.

Comment: Also are you sure you are running mosqitto version 1.4

Comment: I tried connecting to 'test.mosquitto.org' and got this error:    WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org/:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404.

Comment: Also, I created a local.conf in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d and put above 2 settings in it and got WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: @hardillb Yes I am using version 1.4

Comment: Mosquitto does not reuse the same port for native MQTT and websocket connections. The default 1883 port will not allow websocket connections, You should try port 8080 for test.mosquitto.org. For local connections you will need to add the listener to your local config file and then connect to localhost:8080 not localhost:1883

Comment: @ralight I tweaked the config file and now it successfully connects to test.mosquitto.org:8080 I subscribed to #, but it is unable to retrieve the published message. There are no errors in the console so unable to identify any errors.

Comment: Here is a good guide to configure it. Check **Step 7 — Configuring MQTT Over Websockets** https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-the-mosquitto-mqtt-messaging-broker-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

Here is a site which runs a "MQTT over Websockets" server where the URL can act as a client so you can publish, then have your own browser act as a client subscribing to given topic

```
http://test.mosquitto.org/ws.html
```

it might let you tease apart connection issues ... also here is another nodejs library which implements similar functionality

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-ws
```

Comment: I tried connecting to 'test.mosquitto.org' and got this error: WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org/:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment @toothie

"I tried connecting to 'test.mosquitto.org' and got this error: WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org/:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404"

The connection string you are sending seems bad formatted. How are you building it?

For me, the separation of concerns using the JSON object definition to instance the library saved me from a couple of headaches:

```
{
    protocol: 'wss',
    host: `${process.env.MQTT_ENDPOINT}`,
    port: 9001,
    username: 'admin',
    password: '123'
}
```

Maybe something is helpful for you.